# Go-Swagger autogen documentation

Tags: go, swagger, go-swagger

I'm trying to create my API documentation using go-swagger. The structure of my project:

[image: struct of my project]

In the `cmd/main_api` folder, I'm launching `swag init`. Swagger successfully pulls up the annotation from `main.go`, but does not pull up the annotation from `internal` (models, handlers). If I use `swag init swag init --parseDependency=true` then there is a panic:

[image: panic in use swag init with parseDependency]

How to make Swagger pull up an annotation from all project folders?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, upgrading to v1.8.9 solved it !

```
go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@v1.8.9
```